# Ping command not working in Discord.py bot

Tags: python, frameworks, discord, discord.py, chatbot

I just started making a discord bot and i tried to make it respond to ping using events, but I read the proper way was by using commands so i tried that too, but my bot wouldn't respond to the prefix+'ping' on the channel. There are not any errors on the terminal or anything but it just simply isn't responding when it is supposed to. I'd really appreciate any help because i really don't have any clue what i did wrong, I am attaching the code that I started with and it has both the methods of pinging just that the event works and the command doesn't, and I have no idea why. Also I am attaching in the block quotes the response of my bot on the channel when i run the code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
token = 'NzM4DNc3MDI5OTA4ODA3NzMy.XyMeVA.8oopIfcva4IFuhJwO7pkFXy9j7g'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    if message.content.startswith('..ping'):
        await channel.send('pong..')


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong.')

client.run(token)
```

> nandini Today at 11:00
>
> > .ping
> >
> > > ..ping

> balalala **BOT** Today at 11:01
>
> > pong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are defining an event, you are overriding the default event built in. The default event for on_message() has bot.process_commands(message) in it, which allows you to call commands as you might guess.
You see what I’m getting at here, you need to add an
await bot.process_commands(message)
add the end of your on_message event.

Also, please change your token, anyone can log into your bot with that.
I also recommend joining the discord.py discord support server if you need any more help, since they are usually pretty active and can answer your question right away. Here’s the invite: https://discord.gg/r3sSKJJ

Comment: Thank you so much... also don't worry that is a changed token

Comment: No problem :) Good luck